# Matching on repeated substrings in a regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible for a regex to match based on other parts of the same regex?

For example, how would I match lines that begins and end with the same sequence of 3 characters, regardless of what the characters are?

Matches:

```
abcabc
xyz abc xyz
```

Doesn't Match:

```
abc123
```

Undefined: (Can match or not, whichever is easiest)

```
ababa
a
```

Ideally, I'd like something in the perl regex flavor. If that's not possible, I'd be interested to know if there are any flavors that *can* do it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use capture groups and backreferences.

```
/^(.{3}).*\1$/
```

The `\1` refers back to whatever is matched by the contents of the first capture group (the contents of the `()`).  Regexes in most languages allow something like this.

Comment: Huh, I've actually been using capture groups and back references for years in the replace part of find/replace. I never once thought I might be able to use them in the original match pattern too.

Comment: Wow, this is great! I didn't know about backreferences. Today i learned two new things! Just to share: this is the other one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41119233/2619679), what a great day!

Answer (score 23):

You need [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex). The idea is to use a capturing group for the first bit, and then refer back to it when you're trying to match the last bit. Here's an example of matching a pair of HTML start and end tags (from the link given earlier):

> ```
> <([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>
> ```
>
> This regex contains only one pair of parentheses, which capture the string matched by `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*` into the first backreference. This backreference is reused with `\1` (backslash one). The `/` before it is simply the forward slash in the closing HTML tag that we are trying to match.

Applying this to your case:

```
/^(.{3}).*\1$/
```

(Yes, that's the regex that Brian Carper posted. There just aren't that many ways to do this.)

A detailed explanation for posterity's sake (please don't be insulted if it's beneath you):

- `^` matches the start of the line.
- `(.{3})` grabs three characters of any type and saves them in a group for later reference.
- `.*` matches anything for as long as possible. (You don't care what's in the middle of the line.)
- `\1` matches the group that was captured in step 2.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

For the same characters at the beginning and end:

```
/^(.{3}).*\1$/
```

This is a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
my $test = 'abcabc';
print $test =~ m/^([a-z]{3}).*(\1)$/;
```

For matching the beginning and the end you should add `^` and `$` anchors.