# Regex (js) math start and end with the same group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse markdown with `(\*\*|__).*?(\*\*|__)`. The problem I'm facing is, I will match a string that starts with for example capture group 1 (**) but ends with another (__). How can I make sure it uses the group which matched at the start, also at the end? Thanks :)

Comment: Use `/(\*\*|__).*?\1/`

Comment: could you please explain what `\1` and `(?:(?!\1).)*?\1` does? I'm trying to learn from this, not just copy and paste. But thanks! :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928179/matching-on-repeated-substrings-in-a-regex) explains what `\1` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace the second capture group with `\1`.

For details see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233857/regex-js-math-start-and-end-with-the-same-group/67234057#comment118840944_67233857) by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava):

> Use `/(\*\*|__).*?\1/`

And [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233857/regex-js-math-start-and-end-with-the-same-group/67234057#comment118841084_67233857) by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew):

> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928179/matching-on-repeated-substrings-in-a-regex) explains what `\1` is.

Comment: @SpaceDogCS since when can I accept comments as answers?

Comment: sorry, it was automatic, my mistake, i think i clicked on the wrong option